# Combine GroupBy Objects (not the output but the actual objects)

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Admittedly, probably not an frequent case scenario. In essence, I am wondering if it is possible to take `groups_1=df.groupby('something')` and `groups_2=df.groupby('something_else')` and put them into `groups = [groups_1,groups_2]` so that I can iterate over one iterable groups object instead of iterating over the two objects separately. Here's an example:

```
# create data frame    
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.random(20), 'B':np.random.random(20), 'date':pd.date_range("2021-05-01",periods = 20, freq='2W')})

# groupby at two separate frequencies
groups_1 = df.loc[df.date<'2021-11-01',:].groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='M'))
groups_2 = df.loc[df.date>='2021-11-01',:].groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='2W'))
```

Given the above, I would love to do something like:

```
groups = some_concat_function([groups_1,groups_2])

for label, group in groups:
        # do something here
```

Comment: you could use `itertools.chain` with your existing implementation

Comment: @onepan good call, this possibility completely escaped me

Comment: @onepan You beat me, I just hit the post button and then so your comment, sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) for that:

```
from itertools import chain

groups = chain(groups_1, groups_2)
...
```

or

```
from itertools import chain

groups = chain.from_iterable([groups_1, groups_2])
...
```